# Upload CSV and Import - Use temp file?

Tags: php, csv, import, upload

I want to upload a CSV file and use it just for import content. Is necessary for this to use move_uploaded_file to move temp file? Or should I just use temp file uploaded without moving it in a specific folder? Which will be the best practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to move the file around if you do not need to keep it longer than the request:

> The file will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of the request if it has not been moved away or renamed.

from [*POST method uploads*](http://www.php.net/features.file-upload.post-method)

However *if* you want to move the uploaded file around, you should use [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://www.php.net/function.move-uploaded-file) for that operation.